# MySQL consulta con formulación de query

Tags: mysql, sql

tengo la siguiente tabla de registros:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

en donde se especifica los registros que realiza un camión, por ejemplo las filas que tienen un id_estado_equipo 17 son giros ejecutados correctamente. Los que tienen el id_estado_equipo 12 es porque tuvieron una **mantención no programada** y los que tienen el id_estado_equipo 13 es porque tuvieran una **mantención programada** ese día.

Desde esa tabla estoy intentando contar la cantidad días que un equipo (camión) **no trabajo por mantención**. Hasta ahí todo bien, ya que con:

SUM(if(id_estado_estado_equipo=12 , 1, 0)) as mNoProgramada,
SUM(if(id_estado_estado_equipo=13 , 1, 0)) as mProgramada

El problema que tengo es que necesito contar las mantenciones solo y solo si no hubo un giro ejecutado ese día, es decir, si en el mismo día no hay un registro con id_estado_equipo igual a 17.

Por ejemplo, el día 08-11-2018 la mantención no debe ser contada ya que el camión independientemente realizó un giro. En cambio el día 05-11-2018 el camión tiene una mantencion no programada y no ejecuto giros, entonces el contador debería considerarlo en la cuenta final.

Agradecería mucho la ayuda para formular esta query.

Codigo de apoyo

```
SELECT e.sigla_equipo, e.id_equipo,
               SUM(if(ee.abrev_estado_equipo='MNP', 1, 0)) as mnp,
               SUM(if(ee.abrev_estado_equipo='MP', 1, 0)) as mp
          FROM calendar c 
          LEFT JOIN registro_equipo re ON re.fechaInicio_reg_equipo = c.fecha
          LEFT JOIN equipo e ON e.id_equipo = re.id_equipo
          LEFT JOIN estado_equipo ee ON ee.id_estado_equipo = re.id_estado_equipo 
          LEFT JOIN base b ON b.id_base = e.id_base            
          WHERE b.nombre_base='baseA' AND MONTH(c.fecha) = '11' AND YEAR(c.fecha) = '2018' AND (c.fecha <= (SELECT MAX(DATE(p2.horarioOrigen_programa)) FROM programa p2)) and c.festivo = 0
          GROUP BY e.sigla_equipo
          ORDER BY e.sigla_equipo ASC
```